# is it safe to remove zram swap enabler?

Tags: kernel, uninstall, zram

I have recently installed zram swap enabler, which initially seemed great as it made almost everything seem snappier than before, however over time the spike in CPU for compressing/decompressing ram is causing more stuttering and pauses than I would like and kinda defeats the point of having it.

anyway, as I understand it, it modifies the kernel (I think) so I am wondering is it safe to uninstall through synaptic or is removing zram swap enabler something more involved?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean you installed it?  There's no such package.  zram is a driver module that comes in the kernel package.

Comment: you are right, i should have been clearer, i have installed the zram swap enabler

Comment: That still isn't clear.  I can find no packages that mention zram, and it is enabled by default.

Comment: @psusi zramswap-enabler is the upstart script  which can be installed from `ppa` @Jayo  I don't think it will harm anything. Just  to be extra cautious stop the script before uninstalling although I think uninstalling will also do this.

Comment: @sagarchalise Thanks for your answer, I really wasn't sure and hoped it would be an easy process

Comment: Did you solve this problem or are you still looking for an answer? If you did find a solution please consider posting it as an answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to uninstall it.